# How to add QComboBox and TextField inside TreeView with delegate QML?

Tags: qt, delegates, treeview, qml, qcombobox

I had implement TreeView following this tutorial, But I had implement with Qt Quick Control (does not has .ui file). [tutorial here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-editabletreemodel-example.html). With load text and show on TreeView, it work fine. But I had another problem:

I know that a row is a TreeItem and the model is TreeModel extend from QAbstractItemModel.
 - My TreeView has four columns and I set data for TreeItem with its itemData, each itemData has 4 element.

- On Value Column (column 2) I want to add dynamic component (QComboBox and TextField), it depend on value of TreeItem the TreeModel. [The figure below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5r08.png).
- I set data for TreeItem and TreeModel from .cpp file, and set model for TreeView in .qml file.

  - I have a objectA with 8 element (name, value, data to assign component for column 2, current index of Combobox if have Combobox, data1,...) with second element maybe QStringList or QString. My TreeItem get data from objectA with TreeItem (name,value,data1,data2).

I have 3 problems need to be solve:

- First problem, I had delegate the column 2 to all ComboBox or all TextField ok, But I cannot mix them together. When the value of TreeItem is a QStringList, I want delegate for Combobox, and when it is QString I want delegate for TextField. But I cannot access to the return data, I dont know that I need to define it on .cpp file or .qml file. I know that "**styleData.value**" is the value for a cell data, access from .qml file. But I cant to know data Type of "**styleData.value**" .
- Second problem, Another problem that I dont know how to set current index for Combobox on load data. For example: the value(second element) of TreeItem is: [item1, item2, item3] and the current Index is at item 2.
- Third problem, when data is loaded, I change data for ComboBox. How to get current Data of the TreeItem, current Index of Combobox.

Sorry for long question, and a lot of problems.
Please help me if you know any my problem.
Thank in advance.